# When I generate a submenu under an admin menu, it inadvertently turns the main menu into a submenu too. How can I prevent this from happening?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

[image: main menu and submenu]
As the title suggests, I wish to avoid the main menu from becoming a submenu.

When I generate a submenu under an admin menu, it inadvertently turns the main menu into a submenu too. How can I prevent this from happening? Additionally, when clicking on the main menu, I want it to navigate to the first submenu rather than a separate main menu page. Here is the code.

```
// Hook to add the custom menu
add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_admin_menu');

// Function to create the custom menu
function custom_admin_menu() {
    // Add top-level menu
    add_menu_page(
        'Custom Menu',          // Page title
        'Custom Menu',          // Menu title
        'manage_options',       // Capability
        'custom-menu',          // Menu slug
        'custom_menu_display', // Callback function to display the menu page
        'dashicons-chart-bar'   // Icon URL or Dashicon class
    );

    // Add submenu
    add_submenu_page(
        'custom-menu',          // Parent menu slug
        'Custom Submenu',       // Page title
        'Custom Submenu',       // Menu title
        'manage_options',       // Capability
        'custom-submenu',       // Menu slug
        'custom_submenu_display' // Callback function to display the submenu page
    );

    // Add another submenu
    add_submenu_page(
        'custom-menu',          // Parent menu slug
        'Another Submenu',       // Page title
        'Another Submenu',       // Menu title
        'manage_options',       // Capability
        'another-submenu',       // Menu slug
        'another_submenu_display' // Callback function to display the submenu page
    );
}

// Function to display the menu page
function custom_menu_display() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Custom Menu</h2>
        <p>This is my custom menu page content.</p>
    </div>
    <?php
}

// Function to display the custom submenu page
function custom_submenu_display() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Custom Submenu</h2>
        <p>This is my custom submenu page content.</p>
    </div>
    <?php
}

// Function to display the another submenu page
function another_submenu_display() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Another Submenu</h2>
        <p>This is my another submenu page content.</p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: The convention in WordPress is to have the parent menu item and the first child point to the same location, just with different labels. If that’s what you are going for, you basically re-add the parent as a child, see this comment for an example: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/#comment-4771